# Bind two Circle with a Path in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to bind two circles with a free form line using `Path` (by adding severals `LineTo` objects in the elements).

I don't know how to use bind on properties in the case of `Path`. Moreover I would like to change its color by clicking on it.

Here's an example of how it should looks.

#### Example of what I need

[image: Example of what I need]

**Edit :**

Each vertex can move with a `setOnMouseDragged`, So I need to keep each free form of line connected to the vertex.

Comment: Why use bindings at all? If the path never needs to be modified, setting the values is sufficient. If you need to modify the path when circles are moved, you need to describe the desired outcome for this question to be answerable. (e.g. 2 reasonable modifications of the path would be modifying the first/last segment of the path or rotating+scaling the whole path.)

Comment: @fabian I need to drag each vertex, sorry I will add this information !

Comment: I have difficulties identifying 2 circles in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the `x` and `y` properties of the first `MoveTo` and the last `LineTo` to the `centerX` and `centerY` coordinates where the path starts/ends.

```
private Path constructionPath = null;
private final Map<Color, Color> nextColor;

{
    // create map for modifying color
    nextColor = new HashMap<>();
    Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE };
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length - 1; i++) {
        nextColor.put(colors[i], colors[i+1]);
    }
    nextColor.put(colors[colors.length-1], colors[0]);
}

private void createCircle(MouseEvent evt, Pane canvas) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), 5, Color.WHITE);
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    circle.setStrokeWidth(2.5);

    // circle dragging events
    class DragListener implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        boolean dragging;
        double startX;
        double startY;

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            Point2D pt = circle.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY());
            circle.setCenterX(pt.getX() + startX);
            circle.setCenterY(pt.getY() + startY);
            dragging = true;
        }
    }
    DragListener listener = new DragListener();
    circle.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            Point2D pt = circle.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY());
            listener.startX = circle.getCenterX() - pt.getX();
            listener.startY = circle.getCenterY() - pt.getY();
        }
    });
    circle.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            event.consume();
            if (listener.dragging) {
                listener.dragging = false;
            } else {
                if (constructionPath == null) {
                    // start new path
                    MoveTo move = new MoveTo();
                    move.xProperty().bind(circle.centerXProperty());
                    move.yProperty().bind(circle.centerYProperty());
                    constructionPath = new Path(move);
                    constructionPath.setStrokeWidth(2.5);
                    constructionPath.setOnMouseReleased(evt2 -> {
                        evt2.consume();
                        Path p = (Path) evt2.getSource();
                        p.setStroke(nextColor.get(p.getStroke()));
                    });
                    canvas.getChildren().add(0, constructionPath);
                } else {
                    // end path
                    LineTo line = new LineTo();
                    constructionPath.getElements().add(line);
                    line.xProperty().bind(circle.centerXProperty());
                    line.yProperty().bind(circle.centerYProperty());
                    constructionPath = null;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    circle.setOnMouseDragged(listener);

    canvas.getChildren().add(circle);
}
```

```
Pane canvas = new Pane();
canvas.setOnMouseReleased(evt -> {
    if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        if (constructionPath == null) {
            // create Circle
            createCircle(evt, canvas);
        } else {
            // add line to path
            LineTo line = new LineTo(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
            constructionPath.getElements().add(line);
        }
    }
});

canvas.setPrefSize(500, 500);
```

**Note:** It's easy to miss with clicks on paths. If you want to increase the area the user can click you should do custom checks in the `mouseReleased` event handler of the `canvas` `Pane`.

Comment: Thanks ! It should be helpful, I will try it tomorrow, if I have problems I will ask here !

Comment: Why are you using MouseReleased instead of Dragged, it doesn't work with that.